# mysql query return not right when i use decimal

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 select sum(charge) as charges from chargelist
```

If there's no record in chargelist, `$query->num_rows()` returns 1, not 0, run this query in phpmyadmin, result is following

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: compare `select sum(NULL) as thisThing;` to`select ifnull(sum(NULL),0) as thisThing;`

Comment: You can handle this condition by following query.

Query 1:  (Just check if sum is null then use zero in place of null)
'select IFNULL(sum(charge),0) as charges from chargelist'

Or

Query 2:  (Apply case and check there is any row available or not before apply sum function.)
'select (case when count(charge)>0 Then sum(charge) else 0 end) as charges from chargelist'

Answer (score 1):

Well this is ANSI SQL Behaviour as shown in this SO [**answer**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXlc7PhaDQAhWJvo8KHTfzAWEQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F12730457%2Fwhy-does-sum-on-an-empty-recordset-return-null-instead-of-0&usg=AFQjCNFQWhQPw6a6gJK7Db6o5J6KZhOlhw&sig2=IAtdL-1DjzsZ-OftGPn73Q).
If you want to return empty record set you can check in outer query

```
select * from (select sum(charge) as charges from chargelist ) As tmp
where charges is not null
```